# Multiple endpoints or a single endpoint with additional logic in a handler?

Tags: rest, api, web-applications

I am developing an app that will be integrated into different platforms (e.g p1, p2, ...). Let's say users will be able to subscribe so a payload will be sent to the endpoint `/subscribe`.

However the payload being sent will not be the same across platforms `p1` or `p2` (payload cannot be modified). Therefore I am wondering should I have two different endpoints `/p1/subscribe` and `/p2/subscribe` or should I have a single endpoint with additional code in the handler that will check the payload and based on it call the right (sub)handler.

It makes more sense to have a single endpoint in my opinion but would like to hear yours.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a single 'gateway' endpoint which delegates to /p1/subscribe or /p2/subscribe based on e.g. HTTP headers.

The exact architecture depends on whether you merely want to direct P1 and P2 to the appropriate services or actively want to prevent P1 from accessing P2's services.